# Finding the list of all users who attended a particular college using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to find the list of **all facebook users** who attended a **particular college** using fql.

Is that possible?. If yes then, how do I write that query?.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not possible, looking both at FQL and the Graph API documentation. I don't even believe there's an easy way to get a list of fans of the page. The most obvious reason for them preventing this is to prevent marketers from getting lists full of personal information to use for sending promotions or offers (spam).